# How can ı create transparent plastic texturing?

Tags: modeling, texturing

I tried create plastic transarent texture but i didnt succes because i used through glass texturing as you see, 
I need plastic at the same time transparent texture like this:
 [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DEKT.jpg]

how can i create?

My Current project :(
[image]

Comment: Increase the roughness.

Comment: not like ı want

Comment: are you sure this is transparent? Do you have other pictures of this kind of plastic texture?